# Strange behavior of Dijkstra's alghoritm in python

Tags: python, graph, dijkstra

I'm trying implement dijkstra's alghoritm in python. I want to know length from node "You" to all other nodes.

```
def Dijkstr():
    listOfProcessingNodes = listOfNodes
    for i in listOfNodes:
        if i.name == "You":
            i.lastNode = None
            i.length = 0
            i.resolved = True
            lastProcessNode = i

    listOfProcessingNodes.sort(key=lambda x: x.length, reverse=True)

    while len(listOfProcessingNodes):
        processNode = listOfProcessingNodes.pop()
        for i in processNode.adjencyList:
            for k in listOfEdges:
                if (k.inNode == i.name and k.outNode == processNode.name and i.resolved == False) or (k.inNode == processNode.name and k.outNode == i.name and i.resolved == False):
                    i.length = processNode.length + int(float(k.cost))
                    i.lastNode = processNode
                    i.resolved = True
        listOfProcessingNodes.sort(key=lambda x: x.length, reverse=True)
        lastProcessNode = processNode
        print processNode.name,":", processNode.length
```

Here is definition of classes Node and Edge:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self.adjencyList=[]
        self.resolved = False
        self.lastNode = None
        self.length = float("inf")

class Edge():
    def __init__(self, inNode, outNode, cost):
        self.inNode=inNode
        self.outNode=outNode
        self.cost=cost
```

for my input

```
You - A: 3
You - B: 2
A - C: 4
A - D: 4
B - D: 1
B - E: 2
C - F: 1
D - F: 2
D - G: 4
E - G: 2
F - G: 2
```

I get this output

```
You : 0
B : 2
A : 3
D : 3
E : 4
F : 5
C : 7
G : 7
```

Instead of

```
You : 0
B : 2
A : 3
D : 3
E : 4
F : 5
C : 6
G : 6
```

I'm really confused, if it don't work for all nodes, so I make misstake, but if it don't work for last 2 nodes? thanks for your help

Comment: I'm afraid it will be difficult for us to help you as your code isn't complete.  Please edit your code to include the definition of your node and edge classes, and also add the code used to create your sample input.

Comment: Hi, I added definition of classes, but the code for creating input is really complicated, but I'm sure it works fine.

Comment: Where and how is `listOfNodes` defined? It should probably be a function argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a misunderstanding of one crucial part of Dijkstra's algorithm.

As the algorithm proceeds, it is possible for the 'length' of a node (i.e. the minimum total 'cost' from the 'You' node) to decrease if the algorithm finds a route to that node that is 'cheaper' than one found before.  Your code assumes that once a node has been visited once, its length is then fixed.  This is incorrect.

Your graph contains one such situation where this happens.  When visiting node D, with length 3, you then give F a length of 5 and G a length of 7.  However, when visiting node E, with length 4, you need to reduce the length of G to 6, as E has length 4 and the edge from E to G has cost 2.

Instead of filtering out any nodes where `resolved` is set to `True`, check to see if the length of `processNode` plus the cost of the edge `k` is less than the current known length of the node `i`.  If so, you've found a new lower length for node `i`, so you should update the length of node `i` and its previous node.

Incidentally, the length of node C should be 7, not 6 as you claim.